# How secure is the default Internet Application Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, registration, user-registration

I'm programming a website where the users should have the ability to register/login & -out.

I have some questions about the Internet Application Template.

- Is it secure to start from a default ASP.net MVC 4 application with Internet Template?
- Is the Internet Template good enough to use in a real world app?
- Are there any issues known about it?
- What are the pros and cons of Microsoft's Internet Application Template?
- Are there other user registration systems which can be integrated with ASP.net MVC 4?

Comment: How about using Twitter Bootstrap? It has loads of feature that default mvc4 template doesn't have. Also, Twitterbootstrap is default template in mvc5.

Comment: Then I will need to update to MVC 5 ?

Comment: You don't have to, you can just install it from nuget. Here is some info http://www.nuget.org/packages/twitter.bootstrap.mvc4

Comment: I already tried with bootstrap, but I don't have enough time to update my views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet template is using Asp.Net Membership provider which has enough security.
You can secure whole website

Using AuthorizeAttribute you can secure by Global.asax or Controller

Global asax option

in Globa.asax

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Then all your controllers will ask for logging if users are not, to allow anonymous you can use

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

Other way you can use Authorize attribute on controllers or actions

```
[Roles = "Admin, User"]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Even in views you can show hide if user are not authorized

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated){
Html for logged in user
}else{
You are not logged in
}
```

If you use that template it has build it register form which you can use.
[More info about](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

Comment: It's even possible to hide controls in views for non-authorized users.

Answer (score 0):

- Is it secure to start from a default ASP.net MVC 4 application with Internet Template?

Sure.

- Is the Internet Template good enough to use in a real world app?

Yes

- Are there any issues known about it?

Not really

- What are the pros and cons of Microsoft's Internet Application Template?

You don't spend a lot of time doing things which are already built-int.

- Are there other user registration systems which can be integrated with ASP.net MVC 4?

I'd suggest to use newer technology called ASP.NET Identity.  More info - http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity